# Ubuntu 14.10 will not reboot or shutdown on dual boot with win 8.1?

Tags: shutdown, 14.10

My system won't even shut down from the command line. I have to do a hard shutdown every time. How can I fix it?

Comment: Welcome to AskUbuntu! ;-) Go to a terminal by pressing [Ctrl][Alt][T] and type `sudo shutdown -h now`.  Then press the power-off button, unplug the power, unplug the battery.  Plug in the power, boot and repeat with `sudo shutdown -H now`. Is the behaviour similar?  What happens is you press the [Esc] key? any messages on screen?  Please [edit] your answer and provide them...

Comment: Thank you. But was the same issue. Nothing I could read on the screen, but was some script that flashed to fast.

Comment: Output to `tail /var/log/syslog.1`?

Comment: The nearest I got for a reason was. A quick message about a broken pipe in init. It suspends proper.. when I log out it plays the drum sound on a black screen.. when I use restart or shutdown it stalls and the fans speed up over and over. And sometimes restarts on the shutdown command.? who knows I suspect it is not to serious and if I can log out a hard kill might not hurt much... works fine otherwise.

Comment: BTW later I will check what you asked. Thank you very much.

Comment: Another thing I just thought about: can you check your BIOS version and upgrade if there is a newer one?

Comment: I fixed it by booting good old trusty LTS on my dual boot. I ran into more broken pipes than a plumber would in New york city. Not to mention .xorg problems etc etc etc Lol. I think I know why unicorns are extinct....... Thank you for all of your help but that ship was sunk at the warf..... hopeless

Comment: Guess what? It has returned on 16.04, exactly the same.

Comment: Have you tried single-booting? (E.G. Install to a USB stick?)

Answer (score 1):

The problem carried over to 16.04. I didn't have it on 14.04 because of the earlier kernel.  It seems to be an issue with Bay Trail processors.

Now it seems I solved the issue on 16.04 by upgrading to kernel 4.6.